# difference between two functions

Tags: javascript, ember.js

What is the difference between these two functions written in `javascript` ?

`function 1`

```
var a, b;

this.get('obj').then(function(ob) {
    a = ob.get('prop');
}.bind(this)).then(function() {
    this.get('obj').reload();
}.bind(this)).then(function(){
    b = this.get('obj.prop')    
}.bind(this))
```

`function 2`

```
this.get('obj').then(function(ob) {
    a = ob.get('prop');
}.bind(this)).then(function(){
   this.get('obj').reload().then(function(){
       b = this.get('obj.prop');
   }.bind(this))
}.bind(this))
```

The first one is erroneous.

Comment: try changing it to `return this.get('obj').reload();`

Comment: what difference would it make ?

Comment: when the callback given to `then()` returns a promise, the next chained call to `then()` waits for that promise to resolve first.

Comment: If you return a promise inside `then`, it will wait for that promise to resolve. The end result will be close to your second example and your flattened code will be more readable. Furthermore, you *must* chain promises instead of nesting them in order to correctly propagate errors.

Comment: whatever you return from inside promise callback, gets wrapped into new promise so the next then in chain wait until previous is resolved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added some markers to your code for reference.

This is snippet #2:

```
this.get('obj').then(function(ob) { // #1
    a = ob.get('prop'); 
}.bind(this)).then(function() { // #2
   this.get('obj').reload().then(function() { // #3
       b = this.get('obj.prop'); 
   }.bind(this))
}.bind(this));
```

Now, the difference is that it's guarantied that callback #3 will be invoked after reload method completes, in other words - variable `b` will be initialized only after reload promise is resolved.

On the other hand in the first snippet, variable `b` gets initialized independently on the status of the `reload` promise.

**Demo**: here is a demo for you to visually see the difference http://jsfiddle.net/fn93gz3w/ <sub>(remove false && to run snippet).</sub>

And finally, you can make the first snippet behave the same as the second (properly) if you return new Promise from the second `then` block: in this case promises get chained and the third callback with `b` initialization will wait until `reload` resolves. Check this behavior in my demo.

Comment: snippet #1 fails because callback #2 kicks off a reload, but doesn't wait for it to complete.

Comment: @rampion Not necessarily fails, it depends on business logic. If `b` needs to wait for reload then definitely fails.